# Expectation of the jump process of a (UI) martingale at totally inaccessible stopping time.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am wondering if the following statement is true.

> Let $T$ be a totally inaccessible stopping time, and $\Delta M$ be the jump process of a UI martingale $M$ null at 0. Then $E[\Delta M_T]=0$. ($\Delta M = M_t-M_{t^-}$)

Totally inaccessible stopping time means: There does not exist increasing stopping time $T_n<T$ such that $T_n\rightarrow T$ on $T<\infty$.

Cleary by optional sampling $E[M_T]=0$. However, I cannot figure out how to proceed. Does anyone have any comment or idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this proof is correct.

Works for bounded martingale $M$. Define $(T-s)\lor 0$ for $s>0$. Since for $t\geq 0$, $(T-s)\lor 0\leq t$ if and only if $T\leq s+t$. This implies these are stopping times. Now $|M_T-M_{(T-s)\lor 0}|$ is domianted by  $2N$ So apply dominated convergence theorem we have
\begin{align*}
E[\Delta M_T] = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} E[M_T-M_{(T-s)\lor 0}]=0
\end{align*}
by optional sampling theorem.